# laravel : i am trying to get 2 relationships methods in 1 query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

what i am trying to do is getting my tvserious and movies from categories class

this is my categories class :

```
class Category extends Model
{

public function movies()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Movie::class);
}

public function tvserious()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Tvserious::class);
}
```

what i tried and it's working

```
public function CategoryClick($slug){



$media = Category::where('slugid',$slug)->with(['movies' => function($query) {
    $query->whereNotNull('title');
},'tvserious' => function($query) {
    $query->whereNotNull('title');
}])->inRandomOrder()->paginate(8);



return view('test')->with([
    'catclick'=>$media,
    'title'=>$slug,
    ]);


}
```

the problem with this way is in my blade i have to create a loop for movies and tvserious and the tvserious data will always stay at the end at it will show after the movies loop ends

```
  @foreach($catclick as $media)

         @foreach($media->movies as $movie )                                       

                 {{ $movie->title }}

          @endforeach


          @foreach($media->tvserious as $tvserious )                                       

                 {{ $tvserious->title }}

                 @endforeach

     @endforeach
```

so how can i get both of my movies and serious in my blade mixed together

i don't want all the movies to be at first so where is the problem and how can i fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) to your `Category` model:

```
class Category
{
    public function getMediaAttribute()
    {
        return $this->movies->values()->toBase()
            ->merge($this->tvserious->values())
            ->sortByDesc(function ($media, $key) {
                return $media->updated_at;
            });
    }
}
```

Here we used a base collection instead of the Eloquent collection due to merge issues with the Eloquent collection (it does not allow for duplicate keys, thanks @lagbox for pointing it out). After merging both media types together, we also sort the resulting list based on their last update. This means recently touched entries will be listed first.

The newly created list can be accessed with `$category->media`. Instead of `sortByDesc($func)` also a simple `sortBy('column')` or `shuffle()` (to get a random order) would work.

Comment: i would not be so quick to merge Eloquent Collections of different Models together ... if a movie and a tv show have the same `id` only one of them will remain as Eloquent Collections use a dictionary that keys by the key of the model instance.  ... you could merge a Base Collection with no issue though

Comment: it worked but the tvserious will be always at the end of the results .... that means all the movies will show up the after that it will start listing the tvserious

Comment: That's what shuffle would fix by applying a random order.

Comment: I updated the answer with some code that considers the problem described by @lagbox and also added a better explanation and an example how to get a new order in the collection.

Comment: you should be able to call `$collection->toBase()` to get the Support Collection to shorten that a lil bit

Comment: that's great it worked just fine but how i should be able to paginate the results with the accessor i tried the normal way but i am getting Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::paginate does not exist.

Comment: I'm not sure if paginating them is possible, sorry. It would also not be very useful as you are loading all data into memory anyway. You can only paginate on a database query when you use a query with `union` for example, but for that you'd need to have common columns on the tables. Is that the case?

Answer (score 1):

this worked pretty well for me ... #first

i made an accessor in my category class

```
  public function getMediaAttribute()
{
    return $this->movies->values()->toBase()
        ->merge($this->tvserious->values())
        ->sortByDesc(function ($media, $key) {
            return $media->updated_at;
        });
}
```

then in my controller

this is my controller function

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator as Paginator;

public function CategoryClick($slug){

$all = Category::where('slugid',$slug)->first()->getMediaAttribute(); // calling the accessor
```

// Then use following code to paginate the results:

```
$perPage = 10;
$currentPage = app('request')->get('page') ?: 1; // or $request->get('page') if available
$paginator = new Paginator($all, $all->count(), $perPage, $currentPage);

return (dd($paginator));
```

everything is great now thx for everyone who helped me to solve thix issue :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
@php
    $moviesCount = $media->movies->count();
    $tvseriousCount = $media->tvserious->count();
    $maxCount = ($tvseriousCount > $moviesCount) ? $tvseriousCount : $moviesCount;
@endphp

@for ($index = 0; $index < $maxCount; $index++)

    @isset($media->movies[$index])
        {{ $media->movies[$index]->title }}
    @endisset

    @isset($media->tvserious[$index])
        {{ $media->tvserious[$index]->title }}
    @endisset

@endfor
```

Comment: why i cant paginate with the above query ?! is there any way to fix it ?